# react-native-webview don't supported Window?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I use `EXPO SDK 38` and `react-native-webview:10.9.0`,I run the code

```
<View style={styles.mapView} >
            <WebView
                source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }}
                onLoad={console.log('success')}
                onLoadStart={console.log('start')}
                style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}
            />
 </View>
```

Android and IOS is OK, but Web is not OK. I check the `react-native-webview` website,it supported Windows.